# iPhone/iPad: How to make UITextField readonly (but not disabled)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I understand this question has been asked before, but I'm not satisfied with the answers, i.e. by making it disabled. There is a fundamental difference: Disabled view doesn't fire events, but for a read-only view, it should still fire event like (e.g. TouchUpInside), and I need it. Only thing I don't want is the keyboard input.

The reason is that I have several input fields, some can use`UITextField` directly, others are not. I want to have them look similar. So, I'd like to use `UITextField` to display all of them. Some of them need to be read-only so that I can use touch up event for alternative input.

Or there might be a completely different way to do it?

EDIT: This is for my MonoTouch project. I have very limited knowledge of Objective-c.

Comment: It's way easy to assign a common tag value to all the 'non-editable' textFields and check it on the 'textFieldDidBeginEditing' method and return the BOOL appropriately

Answer (score 31):

Say you have 2 text field instance variables connected to text fields you created in the Interface Builder.  Lets call them `myReadOnlyTextField` and `myEditableTextField`.  Make sure you connect the `delegate` property of each text field in the Interface Builder to the view controller ("File's Owner")<sup>[1]</sup>.  Now, in the view controller `@implementation` (.m file), use the method `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and put in some logic to determine which text field you want to allow editing and which to not allow editing; something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL editable;
    if (textField == myReadOnlyTextField) {
        editable = NO;
    } else if (textField == myEditableTextField) {
        editable = YES;
    } else {
        // editable = YES/NO/Other Logic
    }
    return editable;
}
```

From the [`UITextFieldDelegate` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html):

> `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`
>   Asks the delegate if editing should begin
>   in the specified text field.
>
> `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`
>
> **Parameters**
>   `textField` - The text field for which editing is about to
>   begin.
>
> **Return Value**
>   `YES` if an editing session should be initiated;
>   otherwise, `NO` to disallow editing.
>
> **Discussion**
>   When the user performs an action that would normally
>   initiate an editing session, the text field calls this method first to
>   see if editing should actually proceed. In most circumstances, you
>   would simply return YES from this method to allow editing to proceed.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional. If it is
>   not present, editing proceeds as if this method had returned YES.

[`UITextField` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) is a good read also.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> You can do this programmatically as well.  Here is an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // .....
    myReadOnlyTextField.delegate = self;
    myEditableTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I'm sorry I forgot to mention in my question that I'm working in MonoTouch project. From my limited object-c knowledge, I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Actually, I'm looking for a simple solution (like setting a property) if possible at all. If it takes so much code to make it work, I will probably try to find a different solution.

Comment: A dozen or so lines of code is just to much for you? And by the way you are setting a property, the delegate property. And that delegate decides weather you can edit the field.

Comment: @miliu, No offense, but this is the correct answer. Why not take the time to implement it and perhaps learn some objective-c while doing it?

Comment: The only property related to not allowing input in a text field would be to set `enabled` property to `NO` but like you said, that would "disable" the text field all together, preventing events from firing.  But, if you implement the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` method, it is automatically called whenever someone touches the input box and whatever you return from that method is what determines if text can be entered in the field or not.  Running out of comment space... see my next comment...

Comment: I dont have any experience with MonoTouch, but check out these tutorials: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/07/30/iphone-programming-tutorial-connecting-code-to-an-interface-builder-view/ http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2010/07/uitextfield-textfieldshouldbeginediting.html http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-AddTwoTextField.html http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/iphone-sample-source-code-uislider.html

Comment: if you ask your question for monotouch projects, you should ask it under monotouch tag. for my objective-c application, this solution works perfect. I think you should accept this as the answer.
@chown, thanks for the solution. also, I think setting only the editable textfield's delegate to self rescues us from setting if statement under textFieldShouldBeginEditing: event.

Answer (score 15):

Despite the fact you need no keyboard, `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is very useful. It prevents text field from editing but still leaves it selectable in contrast to `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`.

In monotouch:

```
var txt = new UITextField();
txt.ShouldChangeCharacters += (field, range, replacementString) => false;
```

Comment: This is useful when replacing the input view (keyboard) with a custom view (eg. a date picker).

Answer (score 5):

You can have two options:
a) to use ShouldBeginEditing with return false, but you can't use PickerView as InputView in your text field.
b) to use ShouldChangeCharacters that will prevent the editing but will allow to use InputView with PickerView.

Answer (score 2):

Objective C:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  return NO;
}
```

Swift :

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are working in MonoTouch you could use the following line of code:

```
myReadOnlyButton.ShouldBeginEditing = t =>
{
  //event code
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally use borderStyle = .none + userInteractionEnabled = false to make it look like a regular label.